# How to send http get methods in loop Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to get 10 questions by Id using loop. But I get error:
`(TS) Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Question': QuestionId, Content, TestId, Test`

My Question class

```
import { Test } from './test';

export class Question {
    QuestionId: number;
    Content: string;
    TestId: number;
    Test: Test;
}
```

My get method in data.service

```
    getQuestionById(id: number) {
        return this.http.get(this.questionUrl + `/${id}`);
    }
```

My Component

```
    questions: Question[];
    question: Question;

    getQuestions() {
        for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            this.questions[i] =
                this.dataService.getQuestionById(i)
                    .subscribe((data1: Question) => {
                        this.question = data1;
                    });
            //this.questions.push(this.dataService.getQuestionById(1)
            //    .subscribe((data1: Question) => {
            //        this.question = data1;
            //    }););
        }
    }
```

How should I change my `getQuestions()` method to make it works?

Comment: Where are `this.questions` and `this.question` declared?

Comment: In Component class, I will edit my post in a minute and add them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `this.questions` before `for` statement.

```
this.questions = []
```

I believe that your for statement also needs tweaking

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    this.dataService.getQuestionById(i)
        .subscribe((data1: Question) => {
            this.questions.push(data1)
        });
}
```

It seems that you don't need `this.question` instance.

Angular uses RxJs (which has subscription mechanism for async calls). You need to push data inside `.subscribe` function